# PHP XMLHTTP Jquery with multiple div content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a simple page that is pulling in scores for cricket matches.  They are defined on the page like this

```
<div id="bat1"> 243 </div>
<div id="bat2"> 88 </div>
```

Then on my results page i have this setup to display the results.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 bat1" id="bat1">
             88
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 standing">
             198 
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 bat2" id="bat2">
             10 
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I want is for the page to update automatically as results change but am running into some minor issues I cant resolve.

```
<script>
function score(str) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            document.getElementById("bat1").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "score.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
score();
setInterval(function() {
    score();
    console.log("score Updated");
}, 10000)
</script>
```

The above gets the contents but displays there both in the same div (  )

I tried adding in the div to the xmlhttp jquery but this is still resulting in the same.

```
<script>
function score(str) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            document.getElementById("bat1").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            document.getElementById("bat2").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "score.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
score();
setInterval(function() {
    score();
    console.log("score Updated");
}, 10000)
</script>
```

EDIT: Added score.php

```
<?php

 
include('assets/scrape/simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('https://www.foxsports.com/college-basketball/boxscore?id=227334');


foreach($html->find('span.score-1') as $ul) {
    foreach($ul->find('span.score-main') as $li)
    echo  "<div id='bat1'>" . $li->innertext . '</div>';
}

foreach($html->find('span.score-2') as $ul) {
    foreach($ul->find('span.score-main') as $li)
        echo  "<div id='thisthat'> " . $li->innertext . '</div>';
}
?>
```

How can i have the data show in the correct divs?

EDIT 2:

```
function score(str) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            x = eval(this.responseText)
            document.getElementById("bat1").innerHTML = x[0];
            document.getElementById("bat2").innerHTML = x[1];
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "score.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
score();
setInterval(function() {
    score();

    console.log("score Updated");

}, 10000)
```

score.php

```
foreach($html->find('span.score-1') as $ul) {
    foreach($ul->find('span.score-main') as $li)
    $bat1 =  $li->innertext ;
}

foreach($html->find('span.score-2') as $ul) {
    foreach($ul->find('span.score-main') as $li)
        $bat2 =  $li->innertext ;
}
?>

[<?php echo $bat1; ?>, <?php echo $bat2; ?>]
```

Comment: What does your "GET" return?  If you're going to set two fields, then it has to return two values, and it has to return it in a way that you can decode.

Comment: @TimRoberts its returning back 63,54 in the div that shows on the webpage.

Comment: ```<div id='bat1'>63</div><div id='thisthat'> 54</div>``` is the response.

Comment: @TimRoberts That is correct.   I updated my question with my score.php script.

Comment: Well, that's a bit awkward to process.  If `score.php` is something you write, then you should change it to just return the data.  It doesn't need to be HTML.  You could just return a JSON object `("[63,54]")`.  Then, your Javascript can do `x = eval(this.responseText)`, and then x[0] is the first score, x[1] is the second score.

Comment: @TimRoberts I updated my question with edit2.  Is that what you mean?